# python rolling product on non-adjacent row

Tags: pandas, rolling-computation

I would like to calculate rolling product of non-adjacent row, such as product of values in every fifth row as shown in the photo (result in blue cell is the product of data in blue cell etc.)

[image]

The best way I can do now is the following;

```
temp = pd.DataFrame([range(20)]).transpose()
df = temp.copy()
df['shift1'] = temp.shift(5)
df['shift2'] = temp.shift(10)
df['shift3'] = temp.shift(15)

result = df.product(axis=1)
```

however, it looks to be cumbersome as I want to change the row step dynamically.
can anyone tell me if there is a better way to navigate this?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.cumprod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumprod.html)/[`groupby.prod`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.prod.html) with the modulo 5 as grouper:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.arange(len(df)) % 5

# option 1
df['result'] = df.groupby(m)['data'].cumprod()

# option 2
df.loc[~m.duplicated(keep='last'), 'result2'] = df.groupby(m)['data'].cumprod()
# or
# df.loc[~m.duplicated(keep='last'),
#        'result2'] = df.groupby(m)['data'].prod().to_numpy()
```

output:

```
    data  result  result2
0      0       0      NaN
1      1       1      NaN
2      2       2      NaN
3      3       3      NaN
4      4       4      NaN
5      5       0      NaN
6      6       6      NaN
7      7      14      NaN
8      8      24      NaN
9      9      36      NaN
10    10       0      NaN
11    11      66      NaN
12    12     168      NaN
13    13     312      NaN
14    14     504      NaN
15    15       0      0.0
16    16    1056   1056.0
17    17    2856   2856.0
18    18    5616   5616.0
19    19    9576   9576.0
```

Comment: hello thank you for your suggestion. But I have another question, what if my dataset has 1000 row and I want to product only the 4 latest non-adjacent rows? if I use groupby it will product all the value available. how could I solve this?

Comment: @Mango check my solution that is commented in option2, this was already doing that ;)

Comment: thank you but it seems I can't run the code. it gives me error message as  AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'duplicated'

Comment: Then please provide a reproducible example, this works fine for me

Comment: thank you so much. now it works. It is just problem on my side on package installation. sorry about that